# Decal projection on complex shapes

Tags: texturing, workflow

I'm trying to add decals to stairs. I've set up a image as plane on the $X$ axis, and all I want is blender to do is project the image along the $X$ axis. However, through all the methods I try it doesn't work. It textures the top of the steps and I end up with a triangle like texture. All I want is to have an image and then along one axis just apply it to the object

[image: the texture is making the weird triangles and trying to texture the upward surface]
[image: image decal setup]
[image: what the stairs should look like front on]

Comment: don't you want to do it in the Shader Editor?

Comment: i not sure what you mean

Comment: could you please show a picture?

Comment: Forget about "Decals", as new planes to be added on top of other surfaces.
Why is it is such a bad idea adding faces on top of other faces?
3D render engines have a hard time when two co-planar surfaces are parallel and on top of each other, or close together. That will result in a problem called [z-figthting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting), where the render engine cannot distinguish clearly between two or more surfaces and they end up rendered randomly on top of each other.
A more efficient way is combining different textures or materials that are part of the same object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get an angle of your object "front on" by using one of the orthographoc angles (<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> for front, <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> for side, <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> for top, or <kbd>Numpad 9</kbd> to flip any angle by 180deg), and then press <kbd>U</kbd> (unwrap), and select "Project from view" This will make your UV map resemble a "snapshot" from that angle.

[image: Project1]

After that, connect your image texture as normal. It comes out looking like this:

[image: Project2]

If you want to stop the image from appearing on the top and sides of the stairs. you can use the respective axes from the Normal Vector as a mix factor between your image and whatever other material (I used plain white for the example). The Normal vector doesn't like being recombined without a third axes, so you have to do it in 2 stages - one for each respective axis that you need "erased":

[image: Project3]

Comment: this is almost the result im trying to get, however its wrapping around the stairs on the side, and i couldnt understand how to replicate this, im trying to put the image on only the front part of the stairs

Comment: Does the object have to have only one material, or are you ok with using more than one?

Comment: well the stairs are all supposed to be plastic but the decal doesn't, that why the stair are one object

Comment: I edited my answer with a possible solution for you.

Comment: i already have a specific material for the stairs, and the image i want to add is semi transparent, does this method still work?

Comment: Not sure. Try it and see. If the other material has transparency, you might have to do a similar thing, except instead of mixing your material through a MixRGB node, you'll have to mix your 2 materials (bsdf's) with mix shaders, using the same separated normal vectors as mix factors,